# Validation to check if the user has entered the correct format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dynamic grid that has a numeric field in which I have applied masking. Also it has a plus button means the user can add many rows as he wants. The masking is applied like this:

```
<input  type='textbox' placeholder='00000-00-000' data-mask='00000-00-000'
```

This masking is applied when the user enters 10 digit number but it lets the user enter a 2 or 3 digit number  as well. For this I am trying to apply validation while saving so that it checks whether the value entered matches the required format.

What I have done so far is :

```
  value = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val();  //saves the entered value in a variable value
               
                myRegExp = new RegExp(/\d{5}-\d{2}-\d{3}/);
               
                if (!myRegExp.test(value)) {
                    valid = false;
                }
                else
                    valid = true;
```

The value that user enters is saved in varaible called value and then I have defined my Regex Expression to match my value with that expression but somehow this regex expression is not working. Is this the correct way to define regex expression? What am I missing here? My required format is 00000-00-000. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your regex is correct. You probably want to output `console.log( $(this).find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val());`

Comment: I added alert on my value and regex expression on which my regex is returning 
 /\d{5}-\d{2}-\d{3}/  so when it matches with entered value it always go to valid true meaning the format entered is not correct. Why is this happening? @Greg

Comment: I have the regex working here: https://jsfiddle.net/t80h5oy1/. When value matches regex, it returns `true`, otherwise return false

Comment: @Greg what is the purpose of console.log in this? Where should I use this in my code?

Comment: All you need to do is click the `run` button (top left corner). The console log is in the  bottom right corner. It should show true or false. If you change `00000-00-000` and click run you should see the output.

Comment: All it shows is that, if you pass values to the regex it will return the expected results

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but you have not defined the end point that's why it allows to insert more values.

In your Regex it only checks if the 10 digits are in the specific order

try out this

`myRegExp = new RegExp(/^\d{5}-\d{2}-\d{3}$/);`

Comment: If it satisfies your requirement please accept the answer